# Git: share some changes between only certain machines

Tags: git, ignore

Normally, in a Git repository, I have a set of changes that I don't want to go into the main repo, and should only apply to my machine. For example, I might have some documentation or scripts that only I find useful and don't expect anyone else to maintain.

The solution to *that* problem is easy: put 'em in `.git/info/exclude`, and that'll ignore them but not tell anyone else that I've ignored them. And for files that *do* still need to be maintained, use the `--skip-worktree` flag. All good.

Here's the problem: I have several machines - my work machine, my home machine, perhaps also a VM I'm migrating to - and while those changes should not go into the main repository, I want to share them between my machines. **How am I best to share those personal changes between *only my* machines,** without risking pushing them into the `master` branch?

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of a DVCS as git is that any working copy serves as a repository as well. You can commit your changes only locally, in a branch maybe, and then your repo up as a remote on all your other environments to pull from. This way you don't push anything to the central repository.

In case you can create a branch in the main repository it's even easier.

However in both cases you have to make sure that if you branched off from master, you keep merging the changes back in your custom branch if you want to stay up to date.

Comment: This sounds like I'd be working on a forked copy, which as it happens I'm not - but it does give me an idea: could I set up a separate remote for my own changes?

Comment: You could but then again: any git working copy can also be a remote to an other working copy.

Comment: *If* I can access one machine directly from the other. In this case I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, which works for me under these conditions of my situation:

- The repo in question is stored within my home directory (at `~/src/app`).
- My home directory (`~`) is also a Git repository, for backup purposes.

What I'm doing is

- Tracking my personal changes in the home repo, and
- Using `git update-index --skip-worktree` in the app repo to ignore the changes there.

(I'm already essentially doing this for some of the documentation or scripts I mentioned above, where the whole file is ignored.)

This is going to make for a complicated workflow when I *do* want to commit some changes to the app repo in these files, but I think I can work with it. At least I don't have to remember my personal changes for each machine.

Edit: an update to Git since this answer was published means that you can't `add` files in subdirectories that are also git repositories... unless you're sneaky and rename `subdir/.git` to `subdir/.git_` while you run `git add`. (Just remember to change it back again!)